# Train an object detection model using dataset from labeling job

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I've created a public labeling job so people could help me label objects on 50+ images using 8 different classes.
This job is finished, but I'm still unable to run the training job I've created.

Here's how the job is set up:

- Algorithm: built-in object detection
- Input data configuration:

  - Data source: S3
  - URI: the manifest url generated by the labeling job On S3

I'm getting this error message: "Missing image files in train channel". 
Shouldn't it get the images path from the manifest?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to diagnose without some additional information (basically the entire request you're making to the CreateTrainingJob API or, if you're using the AWS SageMaker console, the training job definition).

This is probably the most relevant resource as a starting point: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/easily-train-models-using-datasets-labeled-by-amazon-sagemaker-ground-truth/. You might also find it worthwhile to read through https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/augmented-manifest.html.

It could be any number of things, but my hunch is that it has something to do with the configuration of the training job you're trying to create, e.g., the S3DataType has to be "AugmentedManifestFile," the InputMode has to be "Pipe", etc. All these are described in the above links.